# asynchronous SOAP api call using Python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, soap, suds

My purpose is to make a request from async SOAP api that take a data from pre-configured  database and store it to another pre-configured database. I am using suds SOAP client for it.

```
    >>> from suds.client import Client

    >>> url="http://abcdjkfdsfjlkl?WSDL"
    >>> client=Client(url)
    >>> result=client.service.execute('City', 'Utility','147')
    >>> print result
    None
```

my api call going well and I am getting data in my database too, but I am not getting response from it whether my task it completed,error or in-progress, it might be possible that the way I am using that is wrong,

Please suggest me the proper way of doing this.

Note:- I am developing this project in python 2.7 using django 1.8, In above code I just checked api call by python terminal.

Comment: Is the wsdl valid?

Comment: Hi @Brandon, Yes this WSDL is valid, I am getting data in another database as I mentioned.

Comment: and "execute" is a valid method on the service?

Comment: You'd have to provide a callback for when the async function completes. You might check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569701/benefits-of-twisted-suds-async-way-of-using-python-suds-soap-lib for an example

Comment: @Brandon yes execute is a valid method, that executes a async operation, that is data fetching from db and storing it in another db. Actually here I am getting how to handle callback mechanism.

Comment: I suspect the problem you're having is that the async operation isn't finished by the time you call `print result` since Python 2.7 is synchronous

Comment: @Brandon yes it may be possible, so what should I do for getting response.

Comment: Well that's what I was saying before. You'll have to use a callback style handler to let you know when `.execute()` has completed. The answer link in my earlier comment has an example of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122334/discussion-between-vikram-singh-chandel-and-brandon).